# how do i get selected date from jdatePicker and insert it to mysql database

Tags: java

I am unable to insert selected date from jdate Picker to mysql database 
I need a help please because i have tried by best but am getting  exception. The code run successfully but am getting this exception when clicking ADD button.

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "null"
        at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
```

Here is the complete source code which run successfully but fire out exception when ADD button pressed

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import org.jdatepicker.impl.JDatePanelImpl;
import org.jdatepicker.impl.JDatePickerImpl;
import org.jdatepicker.impl.UtilDateModel;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Date.*;
import java.util.Date;

public class Testd {
    Connection con=null;
    Statement st;
    ResultSet rs;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    JButton btn;
    String datee;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Testd();
    }

    public Testd() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setLayout(null);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            btn = new JButton("Add");
            btn.setBounds(280,350,200,30);

            UtilDateModel model = new UtilDateModel();
            Properties p = new Properties();
            p.put("text.today", "Today");
            p.put("text.month", "Month");
            p.put("text.year", "Year");
            JDatePanelImpl datePanel = new JDatePanelImpl(model, p);
            JDatePickerImpl datePicker = new JDatePickerImpl(datePanel, new DateLabelFormatter());
             datePicker.setBounds(220,350,120,50);

            Date selectedDate = (Date) datePicker.getModel().getValue();
            datee=selectedDate+"";
            add(datePicker);
            add(btn);

            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            btnSaveActionPerformed(evt);
            }});
        }

    }

    private void btnSaveActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
          try{
                String text = datee;
                DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                Date myDate = formatter.parse(text);
                java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(myDate.getTime());

                String sql = "INSERT INTO Invoice"
                +"(Issuedate)"
                +"VALUES (?)";
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/Sales"+"?useSSL=false","root","3000");
                pst.setDate(1,sqlDate);
                }

                catch(SQLException | HeadlessException ex){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ERROR UNABLE TO INSERT ");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex);

            }

            catch (ParseException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
    }


     }

    public class DateLabelFormatter extends AbstractFormatter {

        private String datePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
        private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(datePattern);

        @Override
        public Object stringToValue(String text) throws ParseException {
            return dateFormatter.parseObject(text);
        }

        @Override
        public String valueToString(Object value) throws ParseException {
            if (value != null) {
                Calendar cal = (Calendar) value;
                return dateFormatter.format(cal.getTime());
            }

            return "";
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest that this code `Date selectedDate = (Date) datePicker.getModel().getValue();
            datee=selectedDate+"";` is not working and you have tried to bodge it by appending a blank space

Comment: Read the date only when `btnSaveActionPerformed()` is executed, not before. You don't need to parse the date as you already get it as a date from the date picker.

Comment: Also, you need a `pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);` before binding the date variable. Finally, `pst` should be declared as a local variable and you should wrap all JDBC resource access within a try-with-resources block.

Comment: Your database code is irrelevant to this problem. You'd still get it even if you didn't use a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just as your exception inform. You are passing null value to the formatter. Ensure that

This line `Date selectedDate = (Date) datePicker.getModel().getValue();` can return correct date value to `Date`

And after confirming it can return date value as expected. Change your code by refe code need to delete to prevent the error.

```
public class Testd {
    ...
    Date datee; // Change this variable type

    ...

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            ...

            datee = (Date) datePicker.getModel().getValue(); // change this line
//            datee=selectedDate+""; // Remove this line

              ...
              pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);  
              ...
        }

    }

    private void btnSaveActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
          try{
                // String text = datee; // Remove this line
                // DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"); // Remove this line
                // Date myDate = formatter.parse(text); // Remove this line
                java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(datee.getTime()); // change this line

                ...

                }

                catch(SQLException | HeadlessException ex){
                    ...

         } catch (ParseException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
         }

    ...

    }
}
```

Comment: what is `pst.setDate(1,sqlDate);` referring to? All I can see is a NPE coming to a screen near you

Comment: @ScaryWombat LoL.. why would i need to point out all his problem when he ask a problem not related?

Comment: You don't.  But if you state *refer below full code* then full and correct code is expected.

Comment: Although I think he is still going to have a `null` problem - don't you?

Comment: @ScaryWombat yes, he still.. That's why before i providing to remove the code.. I make a statement *Ensure that This line Date selectedDate = (Date) datePicker.getModel().getValue(); can return correct date value to Date*

Comment: I have changed my code but now am getting this exception when i press button ADD                                                                                                                Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Testd.btnSaveActionPerformed(Testd.java:91)
        at Testd.access$000(Testd.java:25)
        at Testd$TestPane$1.actionPerformed(Testd.java:80)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)

Comment: @FredrickKimaro you aren't even initialize the PreparedStatement. Change add `pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);`  before `pst.setDate(...)`

Comment: thanks @Kasnady  now i have initialize but the problem is still there...

Comment: what is ur problem now

Comment: the problem is amm getting  java.lang.NullPointerException when inserting date